# Salt: install package and run service (name different than package)

Tags: salt-stack

Currently trying to wrap my head around Salt.

In essence I'd like to install a package (rpm) and enable and run the service (if the package installed successfully).

Surprise: The service is called differently than the package.

Let's say

- the package is called x
- but the (systemd/init) service this package installs is called y

This does not work

```
my_state_id:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - x
  service.running:
    - name: y
    - enable: true
    - require:
      - pkg: x
```

Result:

```
Comment: The following requisites were not found:
                             require:
                                 pkg: x
```

It looks like I have to write it like this and reference the state and not the package:

```
my_state_id:
  pkg.installed:
    - pkgs:
      - x
  service.running:
    - name: y
    - enable: true
    - require:
      - pkg: my_state_id
```

But: What does `require: pkg: my_state_id` mean? =D "if the state up to this point didn't fail, then run the current module"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from the [requisites](https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html) documentation:

> The generalized form of a requisite target is `<state name>: <ID or name>`.

If we break up your `my_state_id` ID:

1. `my_state_id` is the ID
2. `pkg` and `service` are the state names
3. `pkg` state does not have a `name` parameter, but `service` state has it, and it is `y`

Since `pkg` state does not have `name` parameter, we need to use its ID to specify it as requisite:

- On the left side we will have `pkg`
- On the right side it will be the ID `my_state_id`

```yaml
  - require:
      - pkg: my_state_id
```

The other way to write the same would be:

```yaml
# give the package name in 'name' parameter

my_state_id:
  pkg.installed:
    - name: x
  service.running:
    - name: y
    - enable: true
    - require:
        - pkg: x
```

So it is a way to tell Saltstack to *take actions conditionally*. In this case if package install failed, then it should not try to start the service (and fail).

Comment: You mean if I were to require `service` from `pkg`. Essentially we are saying (in the original example) "`service` requires state `pkg` from id or name `my_state_id`". Since `pkg` does not have a name, and there can be no more than one `pkg` declaration inside any id, that seems to be why this works. Okay it's crazy but probably very powerful this way =D

Comment: Yes the final `service` example was just to show we could use the `name` (may be a requirement for a config file). Actually we can define `pkg.installed` with `name` as well and use it in `require`. Let me update that in the answer.